# UIPickerView Default Value

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

How do I go about setting the default value for a UIPickerView based on the row TITLE and NOT id?

I ask this because at the moment, I am taking the row and getting it's title, then saving this using NSUserDefaults.

So, when I retrieve the NSUserDefaults data, it's a string with a name. I think want to set the picker view to the row with the matching name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have an `pickerArray` containing objects of `NSString` which you are using as dataSource to UIPickerView,

1. You make an NSString object from NSUserDefaults

   ```
    NSString *lastStoredStr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Key"];
   ```
2. You get index of that string using , assuming array does contain that string , you can have validation about that as per you.

   `NSInteger selectedRow = [pickerArray indexOfObject:lastStoredStr];`
3. You got the index now set it to default selected row of picker

   `[picker selectRow:selectedRow inComponent:0 animated:YES];`

Hope this helps , Let me know if i am missing something.